# how to send signal from one program to another?

Tags: linux, signals

i am using message queue as an ipc between 2 programs.
Now i want to send data from one program to another using message queue and then intimate it through a signal SIGINT.

I dont know how to send a signal from one program to another .
Can anybody pls provide a sample code if they have the solution.

Answer (score 12):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

Comment: how to get the pid of other process in this program.

Comment: there are a number of ways to do this. If one is the parent of the other, the parent gets the child's pid when it calls fork(), and the child can get the parent's with getppid().  If this is not the case, you can put the pid in an agreed location.  For instance, a file that one writes for the other.

Comment: yes. ok. but if it is some other program..? then how to send the processid to that program.. can we send using a socket ?

Comment: Typically, the other process would have to write it's PID to a file for parsing.  But, if the 2 programs share some relationship (parent / child, or they are threads in the same executable) then the PID will be known at creation time.

Answer (score 5):

Signal in linux can be send using kill system call just check this [link](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/signal/kill.html) for documentation of kill system call and example. you can see man -2 kill also. and it's not advisable to use SIGINT use SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2

Comment: I want to add:  it's not advisable to use them, because they are standard signals.   it's  better to use realtime signals, wich starts from SIGTRMIN. they have some important advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Note that by using the sigqueue() system call, you can pass an extra piece of data along with your signal.  Here's a brief quote from "man 2 sigqueue":

> The  value argument is used to specify
>   an accompanying item of data (either
>   an integer or a pointer value) to be
>   sent
>          with the signal, and has the following type:

```
     union sigval {
         int   sival_int;
         void *sival_ptr;
     };
```

This is a very convenient way to pass a small bit of information between 2 processes.  I agree with the user above -- use SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 and a good sigval, and you can pass whatever you'd like.

You could also pass a pointer to some object in shared memory via the sival_ptr, and pass a larger object that way.

Answer (score -4):

```
system("kill -2 `pidof <app_name_here>` ");
```

Comment: This is a *very* messy way to send a signal from one process to another.  How about using the kill() or sigqueue() system calls?